# Arduino-Raspberry Pi bridges

Tags: raspbian, arduino, arduberry

I am building a small wireless controlled robot using the Arduino and the raspberry pi. It works by the user wirelessly connecting through to the raspberry Pi (using vnc or some other form wirelessly) and using the user inputs to send a command to the Arduino which controls the motorised wheels. SO for example if the user presses the up button, a 'W" command is sent from the Raspberry Pi to the Arduino which then reads it and pushes the wheels forward.

I was looking to use one of the new Arduino-Raspberry Pi bridges to connect the two to make it easier to use, but I am not too familiar on how they work. Had a few question such as:

1) How exactly do they work (connection wise)?

2) is it possible to write one python code in the raspberry pi that when run can load the specific ino code into arduino?

3) which bridge would be the most suited for my project? (eg: Arduberry, alamode, gertduino, etc?)

Sorry really new to the raspberry pi and need to find a solution soon so any help would be awesome.

Cheers

Comment: I would not use Arduino, but just Raspberry Pi. You save energy and simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a plain old serial connection ( via mini usb from PI to arduino ) to allow communication between the two.  Cheap and simple.  The serial libraries for the arduino are easy enough to set up, and there are plenty of examples in python or node, etc. of serial comm on the PI.

Oscar Liang provides a great overview here:

http://blog.oscarliang.net/connect-raspberry-pi-and-arduino-usb-cable/